# How to configure with gradle running JUnit4 tests with categories using vintage engine of jupiter Junit5 platform

Tags: junit4, junit5

When we had only JUnit4 tests, we used

```
test {
    useJUnit{
        excludeCategories "SlowTests"
    }
}
```

Now migrating to JUnit5 and still having JUnit4 tests around, how do we use it in JUnitPlattform to let tests marked with a JUnit test category out?

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform{
        // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit4's categories are mapped to tags according to the [full class name of the category](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-categories-support)

So the following should work:

```
tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags.add("com.acme.Example")
        // or the following to exclude the tag: includeTags.add("!com.acme.Example")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!

For gradle syntax:

test {
 useJUnitPlatform{
  includeTags "com.acme.Example"
 }
}

excluceTags works the same way for exclusion